# PHP: A neater way to prepare PDO database statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm relatively new to PDO prepared statements.

I can't help but feel that there must be an easier and neater way to do the following: I load everything into an array anyway, and then have to rewrite the entire thing into a set of **':blah'=>$found['blah']** nonsense.

What's a neater way of doing the below?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE googleplay SET name=:name, releasedate=:releasedate, version=:version, image=:image, url=:url, rating=:rating WHERE id=:id");
$stmt->execute(array(   
    ':id'=>$found['id'],
    ':name'=>$found['name'],
    ':releasedate'=>$found['releasedate'],
    ':version'=>$found['version'],
    ':image'=>$found['image'],
    ':url'=>$found['url'],
    ':rating'=>$found['rating']
    ));
```

Comment: That's what ORM was built for. Have you used an ORM framework before in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to prepend `:` to the key names, it works just as well without. So:

```
$stmt->execute($found);
```

And even if you had to do it, do it automatically:

```
$found = array_combine(array_map(function ($key) { return ":$key"; }, array_keys($found)), $found);
```

Comment: Very nice: simple, and straightforward! I knew there was a better way. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are other ways to do this sprinkled across the PDO documentation, some neater some not. And you can write a php function that does this for you, to make it neater.

The same function allows to use `?` to denote argements, too. For many one shot queries, it's cleaner.

The neatest of all, though, is to use an ORM (Object Relational Mapper) such as Doctrine or any number of ActiveRecord clones (e.g. Laravel).

Comment: Ripping out a completely viable system to replace it with a completely different one which may or may not be suited at all to the situation is the neatest solution...? Hmm...

Comment: Break out the popcorn, kick back and watch this one fly.

Comment: @Strawberry: nah, he's technically correct once you know PHP well enough. But if OP is wondering how he can make his function cleaner, he probably doesn't know he's reinventing the wheel when developing his own framework either, so a little nudge in the right direction can't be bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
$allowed = array('name', 'releasedate', 'version', 'image', 'url', 'rating');
$sql = "UPDATE users SET ".pdoSet($allowed, $values, $found)." WHERE id = :id";
$stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$values["id"] = $found['id'];
$stm->execute($values);
```

where `pdoSet()` is a function to produce SET statement out of supplied array (with checking input array against allowed fields list)

However, the best way would be implementing *another type placeholder*, which will make your code neatest in the world:

```
$db->query("UPDATE users SET ?u WHERE id = ?i", $found, $id);
```

assuming `$found` already verified (means coming not from user input but hardcoded in place or filtered out) and `$id` is not a part of array.

Answer (score 0):

```php
// a closure that, given a key, returns a SET subclause for an UPDATE statement
$cl_set = function($k) {
  if (!preg_match('/^[[:alnum:]_]+$/', $k))
    throw new Exception('Key cannot be used as a placeholder name');
  return "$k = :$k";
};

// use our closure to generate the SQL
$stmt = $db->prepare(
  'UPDATE googleplay SET ' . implode(', ', array_map($cl_set, array_keys($found)))
);

// execute - this works because of the observation in @deceze's answer:
$stmt->execute($found);
```

Comment: oh and it fails with WHERE clause